# Can only concatenate str (not "list") to str was asked and I cannot resolve the problem

Tags: python

I am 2 days new to python I got an error message `can only concatenate str (not "list") to str` I can't seem to resolve the question please give feedback as soon as possible so if you can give me some assistance I would be extremely grateful thx.

this is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/testA/app.py", line 57, in <module>
    print("                                                       " + characteristic)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

```
import time

usern = input("Username: ")
print("Hi "+ usern + "!")
age = int(input("Year of birth: "))
age1 = 2020 - age
print(age1)
if 2020 - age < 15:
    print("Sorry " + usern + " you are to young.")
if 2020 - age > 15:
    print("Lets go " + usern + "!")
    print("                       /)")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("              /\___/\ ((")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("              \`@_@'/  ))")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("              {_:Y:.}_//")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("   ----------{_}^-'{_}----------")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    characteristic = []
    characteristic1 = input("Please Note Your Characteristics: ")
    characteristic.append(characteristic1)
    print(characteristic)
    characteristic2 = input ("Anything else[Y/N]")
    if characteristic2 == "N":
        print("ok")
    if characteristic2 == "Y":
        print("Ok")
        characteristic2 = input("So just type what else: ")
        characteristic.append(characteristic2)
        print(characteristic)
        [characteristic] = list
        time.sleep(10)
        phone = input("Please enter phone number: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Loading")
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("..")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("...")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("..")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("...")
    time.sleep(5)
descr = input("Please write a small description about yourself and DO NOT PUT A FULL STOP OR AND PUNCTUATION WHEN YOURE DONE")
time.sleep(0.10)
print("                                                        " + usern)
time.sleep(0.10)
print("                                                             " + characteristic)
time.sleep(0.10)
print("                                                                    " + descr)
time.sleep(0.10)
print("                                                                      " + phone)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message. Also, remove all irrelevant code details (like all those `sleep` things.)

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: the sleep is for a wait period

Comment: well the issue is that it says that I can not print a list because it is a string and I'm confused as I am very new to python

Comment: @python_man _well the issue is that it says that I can not print a list because it is a string_ Are you sure? That's not what I understood from that error message.

Comment: _the sleep is for a wait period_ I think @DYZ is aware of that, they were asking you to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, and welcome to Python!

You have defined characteristic as a list and then you have appended several characteristics (strings) to the list.

So you cannot print the list - think of it like a container. You need to open the container and print each item in the container.

I suggest you name it characteristics rather than characteristic.

Then you can write

```
for each characteristic in characteristics:
    print(characteristic)
```

You can access individual characteristics in the list with characteristics[0], [1] etc.

Comment: sorry, I'm really new and I think that I deleted the code to put that good code in and I stuffed up even more.

Comment: you can fix the code in place by copying it and if you just want to see it working you can just change your `print(characteristic)` statements to `print(characteristic1)` and `print(characteristic2)` respectively to get the output, but that is not going to really teach you anything about lists. Find a tutorial on lists and how to use them. There are plenty around.

Comment: i tried your code and it said invalid syntax I just don't understand lists I guess

Comment: To spell it out for you, modify this line of code: `print("                                                       " + characteristic)` by adding [0] after characteristic. `print("                                                       " + characteristic[0])` - that wlll concatenate the spaces with the first element in the list.